# Examples of Potentially Harmful Applications to test SafetyNet Verify Apps API

Tags: android, android-studio, security, android-developer-api, safetynet-api

I want to test the behavior of listHarmfulApps() under SafetyNet Verify Apps API which obtains a list of any known potentially harmful apps that the user has installed on their device.

https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/verify-apps#listing

So I need any examples of Potentially Harmful Apps (https://developers.google.com/android/play-protect/potentially-harmful-applications) to install and test the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I found KingRoot to be detected by SafetyNet. From what I've read it's not an actual malware (however it's not in Google Play Store since they don't support root on Android), so it seems to be safe to test listHarmfulApps with that. https://kingroot.en.uptodown.com/android/download